# Logs stucks when deployment is done through teamcity

Tags: java, linux, logging, deployment, teamcity

Recently we migrated to Teamcity deployment from manual process. Ours is java application on linux server.
Whenever deployment is done through Teamcity, logs are stuck i.e. after shutdown log messages nothing else is printed in the logs. Then we run manual stop and start scripts on the server to get the logs running.
Looks like somehow Teamcity locks log file and doesn't release it.

How to overcome it?

In Teamcity, deploy step is defined as below:

```
REMOTE_PATH="/opt/app/$ARTIFACT/releases/teamcity"

cd $TEAMCITY_REPO_HOME/$ARTIFACT/build/libs

echo "Uploading artifact"
ssh $UAT_HOST -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "mkdir -p $REMOTE_PATH"
scp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $ARTIFACT.jar $UAT_HOST:$REMOTE_PATH

echo "Stopping service"
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $UAT_HOST "sh /opt/app/$ARTIFACT/stop.sh"

sleep 3s

echo "Copying new artifact"
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $UAT_HOST "cp $REMOTE_PATH/$ARTIFACT.jar /opt/app/$ARTIFACT"

sleep 6s

echo "Starting service"
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $UAT_HOST "sh /opt/app/$ARTIFACT/start.sh"
```

Comment: What if you delete the log files before the deployment is done through teamcity? Do they get created when the deployment starts?
Also check the user account which is used to execute the deployment when initiated through teamcity. Does it have write permissions? Is the user account different from the one you use when running it manually?

Comment: Same user is used to execute deployment as manual deployment. But yes once I delete log file, its not created by deployment from teamcity BUT gets created if deployed manually. So what should I do now?

Comment: I didn't clarify it but I assume you mean the same "linux" user account and not the user that triggered the team city build. Can you write code that creates and writes to a file? This should execute on app deployment. In both of the cases the file should be created and written. This is to isolate the problem and understand if the issue is with permissions or something else.

Comment: Yes its same linux user account used to execute manually an through teamcity.

Answer (score 0):

Taking ideas from above comments of Andy Dufresne, I created one deploy script as below:
This single script stops server, takes backup of current artifact, copies new build and then executes start script to start the server.

```
#!/bin/bash
#check for correct number of arguments
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Incorrect number of arguments, exiting..."
    exit 1
fi

ARTIFACT=$1

cd "/opt/app/$ARTIFACT"
echo $(pwd)

echo "Stopping service"
bash stop.sh

sleep 3s

echo "Tagging artifact with release"
cp "releases/teamcity/$ARTIFACT.jar" "releases/teamcity/$ARTIFACT`date +'_%y_%m_%d'`.jar"

echo "Deleting old releases"
cd "releases/teamcity" && \
ls | grep -v '/$' | head -n -6 | xargs -d '\n' -r rm -- && \
cd "/opt/app/$ARTIFACT" && \
ls -l "releases/teamcity"

echo "Copying new artifact"
cp "releases/teamcity/$ARTIFACT.jar" .

echo "Starting service"
bash start.sh

sleep 2s
```

This script is called from team-city in its build steps(previously stopping server, copying artifact and starting server all were done by teamcity explicitly as outlined in the question.)
Now teamcity build step looks concise as under and WORKS as expected(that important !!!):

```
REMOTE_PATH="/opt/app/$ARTIFACT/releases/teamcity"

cd $TEAMCITY_REPO_HOME/$ARTIFACT/build/libs

echo "Uploading artifact"
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" "$UAT_HOST" "mkdir -p $REMOTE_PATH"
scp -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" "$ARTIFACT.jar" "$UAT_HOST:$REMOTE_PATH"

echo "Deploying artifact"
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" "$UAT_HOST" "sh /opt/app/$ARTIFACT/deploy.sh $ARTIFACT"
```

Comment: What was the root cause?

Comment: What appears to me is that the path context(application directory) wasn't picked up. So the script to be run should have one 'cd' command or such which can tell or be in application directory to run the script. This idea I got when you talked about log file creation and it wasn't created. So created deploy.sh sh script which cd's to application directory - That's my understanding.